# How can I understand how much space there is on a Linux hard drive?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I am not so into Linux and I have the following problem: I have to discover how much is the sapce of an hard drive of a server (it should be a virtual machine, I don't know if it makes some difference). I performed the following statment obtaining this output (I am absolutly not sure if it is the right way):

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           797M  912K  796M   1% /run
/dev/sda3        64G  5.3G   56G   9% /
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       87M   87M     0 100% /snap/core/4486
/dev/loop1       90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/6818
tmpfs           797M     0  797M   0% /run/user/1021
```

I can only use terminal because I am connected vis SSH.

But I am not understanding what represents my storage drive? How can I understand it? What is it?

Comment: `/dev/sda3` is the most likely candidate for your virtual machine's drive.

Comment: Are you trying to find the size of the drive or the space used by files?

Comment: I agree with chepner. no matter a virtual or a real machine, you have to have a root partition, so that your system can run. In the `df` report, the 64G root partition is very likely your "virtual hard drive"

Comment: All your storage is mounted at the "root dir", ie. `/`. You have 56 giga bytes available on /dev/sda3 device, that is the 3rd partitiong on /dev/sda disc. Grab reads [man hier](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/hier.7.html) [what is /dev/sda](https://superuser.com/questions/558156/what-does-dev-sda-for-linux-mean/558163)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, sda, sdb, sdc, etc. is referring to the physical/virtual hard drive. You can think of them like C:, E: etc. on Windows. The number '3' in this case is referring to a partition on the drive. Since this partition is mounted to root or '/' this is most likely the main partition on your drive.

So to answer your actual question on /dev/sda3 it looks like you have 56GB available out of 64GB.